# Why is `Cell` > `Convert To` > `InputForm` not invertible?

Tags: syntax

I sometimes post code to PhysicsSE, and I usually convert it to `InputForm` first before posting, in order to avoid pages and pages of `RowBox` and `Offset` fluff. I usually instruct the user to copy/paste it into a new notebook, and use `Cell` > `Convert To` > `StandardForm` in order to get everything properly formatted.

Unfortunately, this does not always work. For example, consider the following `StandardForm` code:

```
Q = Sum[Array[a[10 k], {3}], {k, 4}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

It looks fine, and in this case there isn't any need to convert to `InputForm`, but that's just because this is meant to be a minimal example. Now let's convert it to `InputForm` (on Mac OSX, this is performed via `Command`+`Shift`+`I`):

```
Q = \text {MatrixForm}\left[\sum _k^4 \text {Array}[
      a (10 k), \{3\}] \r ight]
```

This is, of course, completely un-runnable, and executing `Cell`>`Convert To`>`StandardForm` fails to produce the original expression, let alone anything which is syntactically correct. Why is this? Is this a glitch with the front end's implementation of `Convert To`? Or am I doing something wrong?

The very similar expression

```
Q = Sum[Array[a[10 k], {3}], {k, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

gets converted via `InputForm` to

```
Q = MatrixForm[Sum[charge[[k]]*f[position[[k]]], {k, 4}]]
```

which is, of course, correct; this makes me suspect that the front-end is getting tripped up by the sequence of two `//` operators.

More generally, what do you recommend is the best way to copy and paste Mathematica code to StackExchange sites?

Comment: Would it be fair to summarize your question as:  Why does the `TeXForm` wrapper break conversion to `InputForm`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Hmm, interesting point, it seems that replacing `TeXForm` with a couple other functions (such as `FullForm`) doesn't cause the error. So yeah, I suppose that is the problem.